# bind combo box with my database inside for loop

Tags: php, combobox

```
<?php
//already connected yo my database

$query = mysql_query("SELECT Module_id, Module_Title FROM modules") or die (mysql_error());

//selecting Module_id 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $id = $row['Module_id'];
  $title = $row['Module_Title'];

}

for($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++)        

  echo"<tr><td> $i</td>";
  echo "<td><select name='Module'>";
  echo "<option>-- Select Module ID --</option>";
  echo'<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option></td>';
  echo"</select>";
  echo"<td><select>";
  echo "<option>-- Select Module Title --</option>";
  echo'<option value="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</option></td>';
  echo"</select></tr>";
}       
?>
```

this code is running but not correctly because only the last data is fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can also process your combo box inside the while loop

```
<?php
//already connected yo my database

$query = mysql_query("SELECT Module_id, Module_Title FROM modules") or die (mysql_error());

//declare loop variable
$i=1;

//in while loop also you can generate the combo box try this

//selecting Module_id 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $id = $row['Module_id'];
  $title = $row['Module_Title'];

  echo"<tr><td>".$i++."</td>";
  echo "<td><select name='Module'>";
  echo "<option>-- Select Module ID --</option>";
  echo'<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
  echo"</select></td>";
  echo"<td><select>";
  echo "<option>-- Select Module Title --</option>";
  echo'<option value="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</option>';
  echo"</select></td></tr>";

}


?>
```

Comment: i need to put the $i value in the first <td> or table data, so it must within the for loop.

Comment: now try select clos is out of td close that's why it's not working. now it's corrected just try this

Comment: if i'm going to put my <select> outside the first <td> then the combo box is outside the table row and table data. It needs to be inside the table data.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$id` and `$title` are variables not array. and `$number` is not defined in your code so it is replacing values to these variables and u got only last value. . Please try code given below

```
<?php
//already connected yo my database

$query = mysql_query("SELECT Module_id, Module_Title FROM modules") or die (mysql_error());

$id = array();
$title = array();
$number = 1;

//selecting Module_id 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $id[$number] = $row['Module_id'];
  $title[$number] = $row['Module_Title'];
  $number++;

}

for($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++)        
  $idval = $id[$i];
  $titleval = $title[$i];   
  echo"<tr><td> $i</td>";
  echo "<td><select name='Module'>";
  echo "<option>-- Select Module ID --</option>";
  echo'<option value="'.$idval.'">'.$idval.'</option></td>';
  echo"</select>";
  echo"<td><select>";
  echo "<option>-- Select Module Title --</option>";
  echo'<option value="'.$titleval.'">'.$titleval.'</option></td>';
  echo"</select></tr>";
}       
?>
```

Comment: <?
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Number_modules as num FROM course WHERE course.Course_id=$courseId ") or die (mysql_error());           
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die (mysql_error());
 $number = $data['num'];
?>
this is the upper <?php?> file of the code where the value of $number came from. 
When i try your code, there's no data fetch anymore but a blank one.

Comment: if you want  to get total number of modules then `select count('Course_id') AS number FROM course WHERE course.Course_id=$courseId` query should be used

Comment: This is the situation guys, in my course.php(first page), the user will input a data(int) in Number_modules field. Then the second page will be a table with rows(depending to the input of the user in Number_modules field). For every rows there should be combo box/es where data is/are binded to my databases. That's the purpose of my FOR LOOP. Thanks in advance. 

NOTE: this code is running but the combo box/es is/are only showing the last data/row of the column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/525090/er-anurag-jain , yes i have Number_modules field/column in my COURSE table.